# angular js bind data-tooltip in loop

Tags: angular, tooltip

I am very new to Angular.  Here is my angular code :

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of mf.data">
    <td>
         <div class="aeName">
            <span class="displayName" materialize="tooltip" data-position="top"  data-tooltip="{need to add data.aeName}">{{data.aeName != "" ? data.aeName : data.email}}</span>
         </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

If I write directly `{{data.aeName}}` in data-tooltip attribute the page stops working leaving no any error.  Is there any other way to fill data-tooltip with current value in the loop?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: if this is angularjs related, please dont use the tag angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of mf.data">
<td>
     <div class="aeName">
        <span class="displayName" materialize="tooltip" data-position="top"  [attr.data-tooltip]="data.aeName != '' ? data.aeName : data.email">{{data.aeName != "" ? data.aeName : data.email}}</span>
     </div>
</td>
```

this works for me. May be this will help someone.